# Oculus Rift - Multi Desktop Application

Tags: unity-game-engine, unreal-engine4, oculus

I am currently thinking about building a Multi Desktop Application for Oculus Rift. The idea is, that the user can use multiple screens like in a regular computer, but can see three windows (left, center, right) when moving their head. (So far so good)

But this is where it gets tricky: On the three windows, I would like to use three different browser tabs or applications that the user can watch and use simultaneously with mouse and keyboard.

Can anybody please suggest how to start the whole thing or is there a framework that I can use? UE4 or Enity3d will be able to give me multiple screens, but bringing the content/apps/browsers to them is what I cant figure out...

Thanks for any help!
fj

Comment: Do you mean like deskope ? https://github.com/AngelJA/Deskope YouTube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QhjTNwa-6f8

Answer (score 0):

You can install VNC Server in the machine and render 3 VNC Clients. This is doable using, VNC Java client and render its output into a texture.

Using Open Wonderland it is possible since it has Oculus support

Regards